# How do you make a $10 \times 2$ $\chi^2$ table in SAS?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have a quick question:

How do you make a $10 \times 2$ $\chi^2$ table in SAS?

Comment: Scroll down to the 'chi-square test' section [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/whatstat/whatstat.htm) (not the 'chi-square goodness of fit' section).

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for PROC FREQ. That will build a frequency table from your data, and from there you can calculate a number of frequency table-based statistics, including most Chi-squared statistics, Fisher's Exact tests, etc.